# The eclipse freezes when I perform ctrl + c and ctrl + v

Tags: eclipse

Every time I do Ctrl + c, ctrl + v or ctrl + the space eclipse freezes for a few seconds and is quite annoying when you are programming.

Has anyone else happened to you? How did you fix it?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's just you, otherwise there would have been a bug report for that. It could be caused by your operating system, a tool or a plug-in that you have installed. But how can one know what's causing it if one doesn't know what you have?

Comment: @howlger Not only it happens to me, in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294135/eclipse-hang-when-copying-pasting-code they discuss the same problem. I have tried to carry out each of the solutions that I propose in the link but the failure persists.

Comment: I don't think it is the same problem as the problem discussed in the over ten year old question you refer to. What do you think? Why didn't the answer help you for the same problem? Well, I also had UI freezes in Eclipse. Two times it was caused by installed plug-ins, one time it was related to Windows. I fixed it by uninstalling the plug-ins. Does that help you? Would you accept that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by unbinding in Eclipse preferences ALL commands on Ctrl+C including the main "Copy". See my answer on [Eclipse hang when copying / pasting code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294135/eclipse-hang-when-copying-pasting-code/71785977#71785977)