# Eclipse JS editor is so slow

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Hi guys i am using eclipse 2020 from eclipse Oxygen, i feel this new eclipse(2020) so slow when open find(ctrl+f) and show inherited member(ctrl+o) compare to oxygen. It's take 2-3 second to open. Did anyone get this problem too?

Comment: Which download of 2020-03 is it?

Comment: There is no "eclipse 2020 from eclipse Oxygen". There is Eclipse Oxygen which is outdated and Eclipse 2020-03. In Eclipse 2020-03 there are two JavaScript editors depending which Eclipse IDE package do you have or what you have installed. For example, both Eclipse JavaScript editors are contained in the Java Enterprise IDE package (see [my video](https://youtu.be/XoUvOTiVaDc?t=584)). The delay might be caused by a (non-Eclipse) plug-in that you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is happening when you use **CTRL**. Please try it out:

Go to **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking** and either uncheck Enable on demand hyperlink style navigation or change Default modifier key.

For Reference:
[Eclipse hang when copying / pasting code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294135/eclipse-hang-when-copying-pasting-code)

Comment: I am having this problem in 2021-03. When a Java file editor is active everything is fine, but when a JS file (or HTML file) editor is active, everything seems sluggish: ctrl+f, double clicking a file in the Package explorer, but also opening and closing the Eclipse About box. So in my case it does not seem related to the Hyperlinking feature (which I disabled just in case).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Eclipse 2021-03 after I upgraded from Oxygen.2. When a Java file editor is active everything is fine, but when a JS file (or HTML file) editor is active, everything seems sluggish: ctrl+f, double clicking a file in the Package explorer, but also opening and closing the Eclipse About box.

I narrowed it down to the Wild Web Developer plugin that I installed to get syntax highlighting for JavaScript files. Uninstalling it solved the problem, but then I miss syntax highlighting.

Googling I found [this post on the Eclipse forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1096880/) suggesting it had something to do with 'Language Servers' feature. I disabled all Language Servers in **Window -> Preferences -> Language Servers** and the problem disappeared while still having JS syntax highlighting. Not sure about the downsides though.